# Social providers integration in Xamarin.Android

Tags: facebook, xamarin

I just trying to add add the `Facebook integration` with my app in Xamarin.Android. For that I found that there is a Component named as `Xamarin.Social` then I am trying that. Here is my attempt.

**Attempt** :-

```
 void btnShare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
        {
            var facebook = new Xamarin.Social.Services.FacebookService()
            {
                ClientId = AppId,
                RedirectUrl = new System.Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
            };

            // 2. Create an item to share
            var item = new Item { Text = "Xamarin.Social is the bomb.com." };

            var shareController = facebook.GetShareUI(this, item, result =>
            {
                if (result.HasFlag(Xamarin.Social.ShareResult.Done))
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Posted", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                if (result.HasFlag(Xamarin.Social.ShareResult.Cancelled))
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Cancelled", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            });
            StartActivity(shareController);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
    }
```

**Note** :-  Facebook login page is opening successfully.

**Error** :- But I am getting this `Forbidded(403) error`. the point is this error is not reaching to catch block , but it is shown in a toast notification. so no further details are available.

Does anybody explored this component successfully ?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I had the same issue and then decided to dump it.  I ended up going with a intent and shared my content that way.  This ensured that I was not only catering for facebook, but for any app that accepted text.

Comment: @Johan Can you share some implementation that use intents for sharing with facebook or other apps,I am just new to android. don't know about it much.

Comment: apologies for the long wait, I have added what I have done as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I had to many issues using the social plugin, I just used the android share intent, see example below

```
  var shareIntent = new Intent();
  shareIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
  shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, message); //message is the text you want to share
  shareIntent.SetType("text/plain");
  StartActivity(shareIntent);
```